# How to paints a transparent circle like using CGContextClearRect to draw a transparent rectangle

Tags: iphone

Do anyone know how I can draw a transparent circle on a CALayer just like using CGContextClearRect to draw a transparent rectangle? My requirements is that I need to draw a mask on a picture, in some cases, I need to erase it, but CGContextClearRect only allow to draw a rectangle, I wonder if there is another way to do the same thing and draw a tranparent circle.

Regards,
Anto

Answer (score 3):

Shreekara's comment is slightly off. Use AddArc instead of StrokeEllipse:

```
CGRect cirleRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100); 
CGContextAddArc(context, 50, 50, 50, 0.0, 2*M_PI, 0);
CGContextClip(context); 
CGContextClearRect(context,cirleRect);
```

Answer (score 1):

Initially draw the circle and then clip the path and then again clear the bounding rect of the circle by CGContextClearRect.

Comment: Could you please provide a piece of sample code? I'm new to Quartz 2d.

Comment: CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGRect cirleRect = CGRectMake(0,0,100,100);
CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(context,cirleRect);
CGContextClip(context);
CGContextClearRect(context,cirleRect);

This will create a transparant circle with diameter 100 pixels...